# How to remove white flash between images when using fadein fadeout method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery. I want to remove white flash between my images when using fadeIn fadeOut method. How can I remove this? Please suggest me if any other way without using fadein fadeout to solve this issue.

I want to show when,

```
x=1, image bg_1.jpg
x=2, image bg_2.jpg
x=3, image bg_3.jpg
x=4, image bg_4.jpg
```

My codes are below.

```
<div id="start">

</div>

<script>

var x=1;
x++;
if(x == 5) {
  x = 1;                    
}
if(x == 1){
var image = $("#start").css("background-image","url('../assets/home/bg_3.jpg')");
            image.fadeOut(300, function () {
            image.css("background", "url('../assets/home/bg_4.jpg')");
            image.fadeIn(300);
            });
           }
if (x == 2){
var image = $("#start").css("background-image","url('../assets/home/bg_4.jpg')");
            image.fadeOut(300, function () {
            image.css("background", "url('../assets/home/bg_1.jpg')");
            image.fadeIn(300);
            });
           }
if (x == 3){
var image = $("#start").css("background-image","url('../assets/home/bg_1.jpg')");
            image.fadeOut(300, function () {
            image.css("background", "url('../assets/home/bg_2.jpg')");
            image.fadeIn(300);
            });     
           }
if (x == 4){
           var image = $("#start").css("background-image","url('../assets/home/bg_2.jpg')");
           image.fadeOut(300, function () {
           image.css("background", "url('../assets/home/bg_3.jpg')");
           image.fadeIn(300);
           });
          }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you put it in a JS Fiddle and share the link here?

Comment: You see white background probably because images are not loaded, try to preload them using `$('<img/>').attr('src', '../assets/home/bg_2.jpg').load(function() { $(this).remove(); });`

Comment: where to put the above code. Can you please explain little bit more.

Comment: You need to pre-load your background images. The flash is because the image is shown before it's been completely loaded. There are plenty of tutorials and question regarding that already, if you Google the term

Comment: can you please add a code, so that I can understand. because I am using if else condition here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using fadein fadeout method I did this using CSS & JS.

CSS

```
   .myimg1 {
        background-image: url('../assets/home/bg_1.jpg');
        -webkit-transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
    }
    .myimg2 {
        background-image: url('../assets/home/bg_2.jpg');
        -webkit-transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out; 
    }
    .myimg3 {
        background-image: url('../assets/home/bg_3.jpg');
        -webkit-transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
    }
    .myimg4 {
        background-image: url('../assets/home/bg_4.jpg');
        -webkit-transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-image 0.8s ease-in-out;
    }
```

JS

```
            if(x == 1){
                $("#start").addClass("myimg4").removeClass("myimg1 myimg2 myimg3");
            }
            if(x == 2){
                $("#start").addClass("myimg1").removeClass("myimg2 myimg3 myimg4");
            }
            if(x == 3){
                $("#start").addClass("myimg2").removeClass("myimg1 myimg3 myimg4");
            }
            if(x == 4){
                $("#start").addClass("myimg3").removeClass("myimg1 myimg2 myimg4");
            }
```